Difference between Would VS Begin to?

From the imprisoned soul, I inherited a new song. By binding the Verse around physical objects, I would be able to move them through the waters with ease.


From the imprisoned soul, I inherited a new song. By binding the Verse around physical objects, I began to be able to move them through the waters with ease.

(Those sentences are equal except for the ones in the bold style)
Do they have actual differences in meaning?

They are not similar, although in fiction or poetry, you are free to invent your own phrasing.

There is no tie between them.


The would version expresses a hypothetical, as in


If I were in Congress, I would oppose that legislation,

so, if you were to bind the Verse around physical objects, then… .

The began to version reports an event that did take place, as in


The moment I got back from my errands, it began to rain hard,

or

The moment I was sworn in as a member of congress, I began to oppose that legislation.

Thus, when I had bound the Verse around physical objects… .

In poetic language like this, I think the first example is ambiguous. It might be hypothetical as you suggest, but it could also be actual in the past, with I would be able to a back-shifted version of I will be able to.

Ah, @ColinFine, so you’re suggesting an alternative reading that’s roughly akin to “There were many summer days when I would lie lazily in the shade” in suggesting a habitual or repeated activity?

No, @Paul Tanenbaum, that's different again - I don't see how the habitual activity could make sense here. The meaning I'm thinking of is akin to "I expected to be able to...". It's future in narrative past.
